# async forEach issue with multiple xmlhttprequests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, xmlhttprequest

I have a question about the async package in nodejs.

Essentially, what i have is an array of objects in which each element contains information that i need to form a xmlhttprequest to a remote server. So i thought i could use async.forEach to fire the requests in sequence, store the results in a variable and use them later in my code.

Here is the sample code:

```js
async.series([
  function(callback)
  {  //async.series element 1
      async.forEach(req_info_arr, function(req_info_element, callback) {
            var url = ... //form the url using the info from req_info_element
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", url, true);
            req.send();  //fires the request
            req.onload = function() {
              
              //do stuff
              callback();
                
            }//end of onload
            
            req.onerror = function() {
               //do stuff
                callback(err);
            }
    }/*end of async_forEach */, callback);
  callback();
  },
  function(callback){
    //async.series element 2
    //do stuff...want this to be done only after we have received a response for every request fired in async.series element 1
  }
  ], function(err) {
  });
```

What happens is this: async.forEach goes over each element in req_info_arr, fires the request for each element.

Once done. this reaches the second element in async.series. But i have not yet received a response for the xhr's fired in async.series element 1, so my code fails.

Is there a solution for this problem? Have i misunderstood anything?

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's because of the callback(); right below the async.forEach, this triggers the next step in the series immediately:

```
.
.
.
}/*end of async_forEach */, callback);
callback(); //<-- remove this guy
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are calling the first async.series() callback right after the async.forEach() block.

You need to remove that callback(); on line 21.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, you both answered at the same time, but StackOverflow shows Furqan's answer on top when sorted by oldest. Tried to be as fair as possible.